# SQL query for parent children relation

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write a sql query on bellow table.

```
╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗======╗======╗
║ ID ║   NAME   ║ CLASS ║PARENT║ DOB  ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣======║======║
║ 1  ║   DAVID  ║ SPIN  ║      ║1     ║
║ 2  ║   AROON  ║ BIKE  ║ 1    ║1     ║
║ 3  ║   LEO    ║ YOGA  ║      ║2     ║
║ 4  ║   LIN    ║ CYC   ║ 1    ║2     ║
║ 5  ║   STEFA  ║ YOGA  ║      ║3     ║
║ 6  ║   GLORIA ║ RUNN  ║ 1    ║3     ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝======╝======╝
```

And, output for this table should be like following

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╗======╗======╗
║ ID ║ NAME   ║ CLASS ║PARENT║ DOB  ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╣======║======║
║ 1  ║  DAVID ║ SPIN  ║      ║1     ║
║ 2  ║  AROON ║ BIKE  ║ 1    ║1     ║
║ 4  ║  LIN   ║ CYC   ║ 1    ║2     ║
║ 6  ║  GLORIA║ RUNN  ║ 1    ║3     ║
║ 3  ║  LEO   ║ YOGA  ║      ║2     ║
║ 5  ║  STEFAN║ YOGA  ║      ║3     ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╝======╝======╝

So this is the explanation of the output
First parent David as his DOB is 1, 
--David three childrens sorted based on DOB
Then LEO as his DOB is 2
-- Leo do not have children[if he did, would be here as sorted on DOB] 
Then Stefan as his DOB is 3
--  Stefan do not have children [if he did, would be here as sorted on DOB]
```

So what i tried?

```
SELECT * FROM user group by ID, PARENT ;
```

Above SQL, statement return items in parent children group but not doesn't maintain any order, when i add `ORDER BY`, `SQL` doesn't seems like honoring GROUP BY anymore.

Then i tried to do joining and end with two complete different tables where one contains all the parents and another one contains all children.   `UNION ALL` on that two query returned expected data set but not in expected order.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

```
Output should be
Pick entry [based on min time ].  
--use that id and find all of its children and placed them in sorted order
repeat for every row in the table
```

Note:

```
--parents are sorted based on DOB
--child's are also sorted based on DOB 
--DOB are valid timestamp 
--PARENT, ID field both are UUID and define as CHAR, PARENT reference to ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d9298/1)

[Similar on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852225/persons-where-the-children-are-grouped-for-their-parent?rq=1)

**Update 1**

Query bellow

```
WITH RECURSIVE
top AS (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user WHERE PARENT is null ORDER BY dob LIMIT 1) 
    UNION
    SELECT user.NAME, user.PARENT, user.ID, user.CLASS, user.DOB FROM user, top WHERE user.PARENT=top.ID 
    ORDER BY user.dob
  ) SELECT * FROM top;
```

returning following output:

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╗======╗======╗
║ ID ║ NAME   ║ CLASS ║PARENT║ DOB  ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╣======║======║
║ 1  ║  DAVID ║ SPIN  ║      ║1     ║
║ 2  ║  AROON ║ BIKE  ║ 1    ║1     ║
║ 4  ║  LIN   ║ CYC   ║ 1    ║2     ║
║ 5  ║  GLORIA║ RUNN  ║ 1    ║3     ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╝======╝======╝
```

Output is good for first parent. But, still couldn't figure out, how can i iterate through rest of parents and their children in sorted order.

Comment: The output looks the same as the input.  What is going on here?

Comment: no just rechecked out put is different then in put.

Comment: The only difference I see is the ordering.  I'm also not crazy about using `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: yes you are correct, two different ordering here. entry which doesn't have children are sorted, and the children are also sorted as they are placed just after own parent.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to show in the output. Also, group by on an id column doesn't make any sense - presumably all the ids are unique so there would be nothing to group.

Comment: Is the parent/child relationship recursive?

Comment: children has the parent id in 'PARENT' field. but it just one step. only parent and child relation, even no grand child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM `user` u1
LEFT JOIN `user` u2
ON u1.PARENT = u2.ID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN u1.PARENT IS NULL THEN u1.DOB ELSE u2.DOB END
      || CASE WHEN u1.PARENT IS NULL THEN '' ELSE u1.DOB END;
```

**Explanation**

1. Alias `u1` has all user details
2. Alias `u2` has details of the parent where applicable. (A `LEFT JOIN` is used so these details will all be `null` if the `u1` user doesn't have a parent.)
3. If the user doesn't have a parent, use its DOB on its own for ordering.
4. If the user has a parent, take the DOB of the user's parent and concatenate (append) the DOB of the user (child).

**Results**

The constructed values used to `ORDER BY` (which aren't actually needed in the `SELECT`) look like the rightmost column here:

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╗======╗======╦════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME   ║ CLASS ║PARENT║ DOB  ║ORDER BY║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╣======║======╬════════║
║ 1  ║  DAVID ║ SPIN  ║      ║1     ║ 1      ║
║ 2  ║  AROON ║ BIKE  ║ 1    ║1     ║ 11     ║
║ 4  ║  LIN   ║ CYC   ║ 1    ║2     ║ 12     ║
║ 6  ║  GLORIA║ RUNN  ║ 1    ║3     ║ 13     ║
║ 3  ║  LEO   ║ YOGA  ║      ║2     ║ 2      ║
║ 5  ║  STEFAN║ YOGA  ║      ║3     ║ 3      ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╝======╝======╩════════╝
```

**Demo**

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6612a/3).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `ORDER BY` which I believe is logically correct:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(PARENT, DOB) ASC,
    CASE WHEN PARENT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE DOB END
```

This answer assumes of course that you can actually use the `PARENT` and `DOB` columns in your query.  You should generally not `SELECT` columns which are not either aggregates or specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If `PARENT` and `DOB` be defined as `varchar` then you can try casting them to a numeric type:

```
CAST(PARENT as integer)
```

You might want to change your table design so that these UUIDs are numeric type.

Comment: Do you think, it will keep the strict ordering based on DOB?

Comment: Yes, I believe this will work.  Please try it and then come back here with what you see.

Comment: yes this works perfectly if 'parent' and 'id' are integer. but, in this case both are UUID and define as char. prent field basically refer to the id of parent. i have also added link to SQL fiddle

Comment: Try using `CAST()` to change the types from character to numeric.  As your SQL Fiddle shows, my `ORDER BY` clause will work correctly after that.

Comment: casting is not an option, as all IDs are standard UUID.

Comment: Then you should make them numeric.  If they can't be compared numerically, how would like to go about doing this?